# Is the usage of "from where" correct in these sentences?

Tags: grammar

I would like to know if I have used "from where" and "from which" in the following sentence correctly.

1. China, from where foreign companies are shifting their operations away, has been hurt badly this year by the tariffs.
2. China, from which most investors shy away, is not a fast-growing market anymore.

Comment: @BellaSwan How about this one: There was a basketball on my closet, from which I took it down and looked at it closely.

Comment: This one is also correct

Comment: @BellaSwan I am wondering whether "from where" is better in the sentence above.

Comment: I'd beg to differ, because "where" is usually used for a real place. Closet is usually considered an object rather than a place, hence "which" will be used.

Comment: I agree with you. So, let me make this clear
1. There was a pen on the table, from which I picked it up and examined it closely. (Table as an object)

2.  There was a pen under the table, from where I picked it up and examined it closely. (under table as a place) 

Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. Also, looking at the second example again, the basketball is ON the closet, not inside it, right? In that case, WHERE would be used, as "on the closet" is a place.

Comment: @BellaSwan Yes I know what you mean. But I thought you preferred "from which" to "from where" in that case.  

1. There was a basketball on my closet, "from which" I took it down and looked at it closely. 
Even if the basketball is in the closet, from which should be used. 

2. There was a basketball in my closet, from which I took it out.

Comment: I think "where" would be used with ON and "which" with IN

Comment: So you mean it should be: There was basketball on my closet, "from where" I took it down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96343/discussion-between-chien-te-lu-and-bella-swan).